# Constant expression required with buttons

Tags: android

After long time I tried to update my app and I am in trouble. I get the error "constant expression required" for R.id.buttonSpeak. How can I fix it?

```
public void onClick(View view) {

switch (view.getId()) {

        case R.id.buttonSpeak:
            app.virg.firstrelease.Virgi.speakWords(et.getText().toString());
            if (app.virg.firstrelease.Virgi.myTTS.isSpeaking()) et.getText().clear();
            break;

        case R.id.buttonEsc:
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
            finish();
            break;

        default: break;
    }}
```